# how to resolve Call to undefined function mssql_connect() in xampp 1.8.2-6

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

i'm trying to connect mssql with php. I have xampp 1.8.2-6 version installed on windows 8 with php version 5.4.31 i had installed driver with files `php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll` and `php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dl`l and edit `php.ini` with extension values

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
```

and check the sqlsrv configuration value.

but still showing same error i'm attaching the piece of code

```
$con=mssql_connect("myserver","user", "PASS");
```